# Где разместить игру на html/js? Как сохранять пользовательские данные в такой игре?

Tags: javascript, сервер, хостинг

!Привет. Я почти написал мини игру - алхимик, но знаю только html, css, js, и то, поверхностно. Я хочу сделать так, чтобы можно было как-нибудь сохранить свою игру, потому что рецептов много, и времени она займет много. Так вот, можно-ли где либо найти какой то простой код на питоне или php или может даже на js, и что можно использовать вместо сервера, обязательно ли покупать где то место, или можно использовать место на хостинге( вопросы может быть глупые, но я первый раз собираюсь выгружать сайт на хостинг, и незнаю что да как ). Заранее спасибо)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если никакой серверной логики не нужно, вы можете использовать [github-pages](https://pages.github.com/) для хостинга Вашей игры.

---

Все пользовательские данные можно сохранять в [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), это хранилище на клиенте в браузере.

Сохранить данные в локальное хранилище:

```
localStorage.setItem('recipe-1', 'example data');
```

Получить данные:

```
let data = localStorage.getItem('recipe-1');
```

---

Если же Вам хочется получить постоянное хранение данных, можно воспользоваться одним из бесплатных публичных хранилищ:

https://www.jsonstore.io/

https://jsonbin.io/

http://myjson.com/

---

Еще один вариант - экспортировать состояние полностью, если это возможно, например в виде ссылки. Из нее же при входе это состояние восстанавливать.

Я этот фокус использовал вот в этой своей поделке с explorer'ом фракталов в комплексной плоскости:

[classic mandelbrot set](https://strangerintheq.github.io/mandelbrot.html?eyJ4IjotMS40ODI4MzMwNDQwNjAzNzE2LCJ5IjotMC4wMDAyNTI0MTY1NzAzMjU1MTY3MywiaSI6IjI0OCIsImEiOiI1MCIsImIiOiI1MCIsInQiOiIxMCIsInoiOjAuMDAyOTA2MDYyMTYxNjYxMTI2LCJmb3JtdWxhIjoiZWlBOUlHMTFiQ2g2TENCNktTQXJJR003In0=)

[burning ship fractal](https://strangerintheq.github.io/mandelbrot.html?eyJ4IjoxLjg2MDI5MTg0NTcxNDA2NTQsInkiOjAuMDAxNDgzNzI3OTQzODQ0Nzk4MSwiaSI6IjI0OCIsImEiOiI1MCIsImIiOiI1MCIsInQiOiIxMCIsInoiOjAuMDA0MjcxMTc0MTU1MTc4MDg4LCJmb3JtdWxhIjoiZWlBOUlHMTFiQ2hoWW5Nb2Vpa3NJR0ZpY3loNktTa2dMU0JqT3c9PSJ9)

[julia set animated](https://strangerintheq.github.io/mandelbrot.html?eyJ4IjowLjAzNjUwMTc5NTYxMjcyOTk1NCwieSI6MC4wMTk5MjU3MTQ0OTE5NDcwOSwiaSI6IjI1NiIsImEiOiI1MCIsImIiOiI1MCIsInQiOiIxMCIsInoiOjEuMjkzNzU3OTE3NDUwMzQ5MywiZm9ybXVsYSI6ImVpQTlJRzExYkNoNkxDQjZLU0F0SUhRNyJ9)

Переходя по этим ссылкам вы передаете состояние скрипту на странице, как часть `url`, там зашифрован `json` в `base64`

Comment: Про локальное хранилище я знаю, и как раз пользуюсь им, на случай, если юзер страницу закроет там или перезагрузит. Но хочется, чтобы с разных устройств можно было заходить, потому что если игра и понравится кому, на телефоне будет удобнее играть

Comment: @EliseyPopov дополнил ответ